# Como filtrar lista de clientes ativos em determinado período

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Bom dia a todos. Estou desenvolvendo um software de gestão para uma empresa de home care. Tenho uma lista de clientes que podem estar ativos ou inativos dentro de determinado mês. Cada cliente tem um valor de contrato com a empresa e custos que gera em cada mês. Para calcular o lucro liquido da empresa dentro de determinado mês gerei um scaffold para mês. Preciso em cada mês pegar a lista de clientes ativos naquele período, como posso fazer isso? Uma consulta aos clientes com condição = ativo dentro de certo período? Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: O que define um cliente como "ativo"? Alguma fatura salva em outra tabela, para determinado mês?

Comment: acho que deveria criar pelo menos uma coluna "último acesso", e sempre que o cara realizar uma ação no sistema, ou pelo menos a cada 10 minutos checar no sistema se ele permanece online atualizar a data de "último acesso", no filtro de busca do SQL para você visualizar, basta trazer os registros onde a data for maior ou menor que o período que você quer colocar de limite

Comment: A pergunta é a do @Cleber Griff , o que é um "cliente ativo" sem saber isto não dá para falar nada.

Comment: Isso, @Motta!
Eu imaginei que um cliente "ativo" seria um cliente que tenha alguma fatura criada em determinado período. Se for esse o caso, seria simplesmente executar uma query no estilo ``WHERE datafatura BETWEEN data_inicial AND data_final``

Comment: Fala galera. Cliente ativo é o cliente que paga mensalidade. No caso desta empresa os clientes ficam inativos pq morrem kkkk. Resumindo eu preciso somar os valores de mensalidade dos clientes ativos e subtrair os custos gerados com esse mesmo cliente para chegar no lucro liquido. O lucro liquido do mes é a soma do lucro liquido de cada cliente ATIVO, por isso preciso saber como filtrar os clientes ativos em janeiro, em fevereiro, etc.